# Spring Data Rest links incorrect after upgrading to spring boot 2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

After upgrading the spring boot starter parent from 2.0.6.RELEASE to 2.1.0.RELEASE, the links generated by spring data rest no longer have the host of the UI but instead have the host of the API microservice. Is there an application property or setting that needs to be added.

I compared the request headers of the request when using each of the versions and they haven't changed while checking if may have been causing the issue.

I noticed that in the 'getting started' guide for rest hateoas

> Spring HATEOAS respects various X-FORWARDED- headers

But I never set those headers in the previous version. Should those be added.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you open up a bug on GitHub?

Comment: Added bug in GitHub https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15109